# How to find if a string contains a word between two colons, then return that result including the colons

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm writing a bot for Discord, and I want to be able to detect if a string contains a substring that is in the format `:smilie:`, for example

"I am so excited for this video game! :getin:".

Currently the way I have it set up, if a user posts a separate message, ie.

I am so excited for this video game!

:getin:

my bot will attach the smilie by using this algorithm

```
case startsWith(message, ":"):
    channel.uploadFile("saemotes/"+message+".png");
    channel.uploadFile("saemotes/"+message+".gif");
break;
```

This works fine, however I would like it to be more elegant. All image files for the emotes are named `:smilie_name:.png/.gif` depending on what it is, so based on that, what would be the best regex expression to pull the potential file name out of a string? I'm assuming it would be something like

```
case S(message).match(/\b:smilie_name:\b/) !== null:
    smilie_name_parsed_from_regex = <regex_result>;
    channel.uploadFile("saemotes/"+<smilie_name_parsed_from_regex>+".png");
    channel.uploadFile("saemotes/"+<smilie_name_parsed_from_regex>+".gif");
break;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are relating a name to a jpeg, you have to actually match from a list of names, not just some random name matching. Make a regex with all the names available  `:(name1|name2|name3|name4|...|nameLast):` Otherwise, you're going to get some random junk.

Comment: that would be fine, however I have over 1000 images for it to potentially match with, so at this scale that isn't exactly practical. If it doesn't match with an image result, it returns nothing

Comment: Over a thousand huh? Consider this a regex with over **[175,000](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt)** names. It takes less than 5 steps to find any one of them. Not only practical, but scary fast !! Use the _[Strings to Regex - Ternary Tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg)_ from **[RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com)** or give me a link to them and I'll make one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a minor alteration to your regex should do the trick:

```
case /:([\w]+):/g.test(S(message)) === true:
    var images = S(message).match(/:([\w]+):/g);
    // map matches into urls and upload
    images.map(function(image) {
       return 'saemotes/'+image.replace(/:/g, '')+'.png';
    }).forEach(channel.uploadFile);
break;
```

Comment: Great, glad to help! :D

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to use is:

```
:[A-Za-z]++:
```

This pattern matches any pair of colons with at least one (therefore the +) alphabetical characters inside. The second plus is used to make the + possesive, that means it is taking as many characters as popossib and won't backtrack in case of a fail. This is not certainly necessary, but improves performance slightly.

Comment: How would I return this result instead of just checking that it is currently present so that I can use it in the algorithm?

Comment: With [string.match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) you can get an array of the strings that match the given pattern.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!